How to create an app with Android Studio in Java language
I would like to create an app with Android Studio in Java language. When I create my project I select Empty Activity I don't find the java option in Build Configuration Language. What do I have to do to create the project in Java language? I installed Android Studio Koala 2024.1.1. Thank you.
I couldn't find any information regarding my problem

When you create new project,select "Empty Views Activity", no "Empty Activity" and you have option to select which language you want to use Java or Kotlin.

You can see the "java language" option when follow below order
create new project and when choose a template
"Empty Activity" > There is no Language Select Panel with Android Studio Koala | 2024.1.1 Patch 1 version.
"Empty Views Activity" still shows Language Select Panel.

It's not clear (to me) whether you are answering the question or saying that you have a similar problem. if the latter, then you need to post a question.

Thanks for comment. I have added explanation before step.


Instead of using "Empty Activity" use "Empty views Activity".
